# Reopen: How to approach new job when interviewed for one role and then the same team offered another role?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[How to approach new job when interviewed for one role and then the same team offered another role?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/108162/how-to-approach-new-job-when-interviewed-for-one-role-and-then-the-same-team-off)

The OP has a comment there that might have been missed:

> What needs to be done to get this off hold? Multiple modifications to the question have been made to address concerns. – hawkeye 2 days ago

Posting this to discuss reopening and/or what needs to happen for that user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [reworded the question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/108162/4) to be more in line with OP's clarifications under [IDrinkandIKnowThings's answer](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5113/3192). I have also cast an undelete vote and a reopen vote.

If the question is now acceptable, please cast undelete and reopen votes.

Comment: as far as I can tell your edit invalidated [the answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/108179/168) that was posted against the original question revision

Comment: @gnat I saw that answer, but what question was that trying to answer? I read that 4 times, and cannot see any relevance to the original question.

Comment: well upon re-checking old revision, you definitely have a point here. Though the prior revision of the question was rather vague which kind of obscured that answer barely relates if at all, while clarified question makes discrepancy very prominent and possibly confusing to readers. I would consider commenting the answer and suggesting them to adjust to changes made to the question

Comment: I cast another undelete vote and just now the final reopen vote (5/5).

Comment: @enderland what's your take on the answer invalidated by the question edit? (this is briefly discussed above)

Comment: FWIW, *my* take on that is since the "answer" wasn't valid to the original version, it cannot be invalidated, by definition. If someone posts an irrelevant "answer" when the question is unclear *instead of first getting the question fixed*, then they should not be "eligible" for the "edit invalidation protection" (if you will).

Answer (score 2):

The OP has already accepted the new role.  There is nothing we can do to help them.  Even if the OP was still considering the choice, then the question becomes about a specific choice, which is off topic.

In order to reopen this question I think we need a goal that is on topic.  There is no on topic goal that I can see to even suggest to the op.  The OP's situation sucks.  The options are embrace the new role, or find a new job.  The time to have the discussion about the new position was before the new position was accepted.

Comment: The question is not about accepting a role. The question is about how to approach people in the workplace. They were told one thing, and now I have to explain to them its another - even though I and the manager agreed it would be different. I have to approach them as if they feel they've been misled in the situation.

Comment: @hawkeye Why do you think you need to approach people differently?  Maybe that is the piece i am missing here.

Comment: @Hawkeye Or are you asking how to passive-agressively show your disapproval of the switch?  (That is a valid question I would support btw if that is your intent)

Comment: I’m asking how to help them in their confusion in an uncomfortable situation. They assented to me being their leader in one role. Now I’m coming in as a consultant which isn’t what they agreed to at all.

Comment: @hawkeye - That part is not at all clear. also not clear is what is the difference in the role and why is it causing confusion.  I assume this role existed and you are capable of performing in that role?

Comment: Cool - can we delete it then?

Comment: @Hawkeye Do you want the question deleted? - If so flag the question and ask the mods to delete it and they should.

Comment: I have flagged it and asked for deletion. What happens if they don't delete it in a day or two?